# What is the difference to deploy Kafka with Debezium on Kubernetes clusters in terms of managing scalability?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, debezium

I am going to start a big open source project on github. I'd like to create sсalable failure tolerate cloud order matching engine with as high TPS as possible. I chose to use event-driven microservice architecture backed by kafka topics. Services are to be written with Go. It is supposed that engine is to be deployed on kubernetes clusters.

I know that there are Bitnami and Confluent zoo/kafka helm charts. Bitnami kafka chart is working quit well for me on Minikube.

Also I'd like to use Debezium connect.

So I would be very grateful for any experience of deploying and using Kafka with Debezium  on Kubernetes clusters especially in terms of scalability. Thanks.